# Need support for ERC in KiCad

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, kicad

I am a beginner in KiCad and looking for support for following errors in ERC KiCad -
[image]

Below are the Eeschema snapshots for reference -
[image]
[image]

How shall I resolve these errors?

Comment: Thanks for editing the post @winny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** one tells you Kicad doesn't know about the PWR_FLAG before D8. You need a new one after D8.

**Second** is a bit tricky. Right click on U6, choose Update symbol, and Update button. If ERC still complain, repeat but instead of Update you choose Change symbol, and Change.

**Third** is about you have connected the 3.3V and +3.3V (notice the difference) power symbols to the same net.

**Fourth** should be resolved if you remove that PWR_FLAG, but i'm not 100% on this one.

Comment: Thanks @MiNiMe, 1st, 4th errors and 3rd warning are resolved. 2nd warning is still occurring. I tried updating and changing the symbol in the symbol editor, but it is not getting reflected in Eeschema. Let me try the method suggested by Andy aka

Comment: I've had that too, and it wasn't easy to solve my memory tells me. My search was fruitless for quite some time before I found the solution. I recently signed up to the Kicad forums, and I can recommend it, since it's all about one software you get excellent help.

Comment: Sure, I'll sign up in Kicad forum.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a power flag to the net in the schematic
2. Sounds like the symbol has been modified but not updated onto the schematic. Try updating it. If it becomes an incorrect symbol then save your currently used symbol locally and, link to it to prevent further errors
3. Sounds like you have named a net in two places with slightly different names. Not really a problem but, you need to double-check this isn't something else. Highlight the net and visually work through it from end-to-end.
4. This isn't usually a problem. Many chips have pins (defined as being outputs) connected to similar chips. Double-check it isn't a circuit mistake and, either exclude that error from being reported or, edit the symbol to change one of the pins to being "passive".

Comment: 4 is arguably a bug--it appears that KiCad is treating the "power flag" symbol, intended as a way to indicate that this is a power rail, as if it were an actual device outputting power.

Comment: @Hearth it might be.